# word2vec using tf-idf and visulaization

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, jupyter-notebook, computer-science

I want to use word2vec with tfidf on amazon reviews dataset but i can't figure out how to do it....i have sampled the data which contains 5k reviews with a positive score and 5k negative score.......there is a column score which corresponds to  +ve or -ve . i tried but i have the following errors......

```
#TF-IDF


final_tf_idf = tf_idf_vect.fit_transform(final_data['CleanedText'].values)
tfidf_feat = tf_idf_vect.get_feature_names()
 # tfidf words/col-names
# final_tf_idf is the sparse matrix with row= sentence, col=word and cell_val = tfidf

tfidf_sent_vectors = []; # the tfidf-w2v for each sentence/review is stored in this list
row=0;
for sent in list_of_sent: # for each review/sentence
    sent_vec = np.zeros(50) # as word vectors are of zero length
    weight_sum =0; # num of words with a valid vector in the sentence/review
    for word in sent: # for each word in a review/sentence
        try:
            vec = w2v_model.wv[word]
            # obtain the tf_idfidf of a word in a sentence/review
            tfidf = X[row, tfidf_feat.index(word)]
            sent_vec += (vec * tfidf)
            weight_sum += tfidf
        except:
            pass
    sent_vec /= weight_sum
    print(np.isnan(np.sum(sent_vec)))

    tfidf_sent_vectors.append(sent_vec)
    row += 1
```

Error:invalid value encountered in true_divide
looks like i'm having NaN values in every row of sent_vec

Any help would be appreciated...!!

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with the below line of code

```
tfidf = X[row, tfidf_feat.index(word)]
```

Here 'X' is not your vector rather replace it with final_tf_idf

```
tfidf = final_tf_idf [row, tfidf_feat.index(word)]
```

Try it out and let me know.